# How to write a redirect and only change specific string in it?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have different products on my website, with something like this

https://www.mywebsite.com/products/productxy123

but this is my old URL structure.

Now I have something like this

https://www.mywebsite.com/newproductoverview/productxy123

How can I redirect to newproductoverview/and the given productname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/(.+)$ /newproductoverview/$1
```